# labelsAtPosition(qgsPoint) is not working properly

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

I try to use function `QgsLabelingResults().labelsAtPosition(qgsPoint)`, which gives as a result list of labels at QGIS point.

```
labels = QgsLabelingResults().labelsAtPosition(qgsPoint)
```

Problem is that list is always empty no matter I do. My question is: Does it work properly? Have you seen example of using it that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works - but your code is actually creating a new, empty labeling results when you call

```
QgsLabelingResults()
```

I suspect what you're actually after is:

```
labels = iface.mapCanvas().labelingResults().labelsAtPosition(...)
```

Comment: Wow, that really helped me! I saw using this function that way (QgsLabelingResults().labelsAtPosition(qgsPoint)) in Plugin named EasyCustomLabeling so I assumed it works that way.